# Fail to upload a document to BIM360/ACC with node

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I am following the following step by step guide (https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/)
I am using node.js with axios package to do all the web requests.
The response I get at step 6 seems to be ok (i get status 200 :)
When I move to step 7 , I get an error stating :

```
errors: [
        {
          id: 'dcda72b1-04c2-441b-a928-aafbb1d32d39',
          status: '400',
          code: 'BAD_INPUT',
          title: 'Object violates schema "create_item".',
          detail: 'See meta section for details.'
        }
      ],
```

I think the issue has something to do with my translation of the cUrl command from the tutorial  into Javascript and substituting the parameters I am missing something , how do I check this ?
A console.log of the JSON.Stringify(data) output follows :

```
{"jsonapi":{"version":"1.0"},"data":{"type":"items","attributes":{"displayName":"testing.pdf","extension":{"type":"items:autodesk.core:File","version":"1.0"}},"relationships":{"tip":{"data":{"type":"versions","id":"1"}},"parent":{"data":{"type":"folders","id":"urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.hRlS3cVYRhuXeBmzluk9Ug"}}}},"included":[{"type":"versions","id":"1","attributes":{"name":"testing.pdf","extension":{"type":"versions:autodesk.core:File","version":"1.0"}},"relationships":{"storage":{"data":{"type":"objects"}}}}]}
```

Any idea is welcome. thanks Jonathan

Comment: According to the tutorial and the documentation, you need to add the id of the file `included > relationships > storage > data > id`. The step 7 of the tutorial describes how to construct this `urn`.

Comment: Hi @AlexAR ,
Thanks - it turns out the I did not pull the id from the response so your comment led me to the right direction. Now I get a 403 response - 
Type 'items:autodesk.core:File' is not allowed in folder , which I am not sure why because I can upload a pdf file .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For uploading files to BIM360 or ACC, the item extension should be `items:autodesk.bim360:File`, not `items:autodesk.core:File`. and the version extension should be `versions:autodesk.bim360:File`, not `versions:autodesk.core:File`.

ref: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/document-management/upload-document-s3/

Comment: Thanks @Eason Kang
I now get a different error :
 cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
    errno: -4078,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
My guess is that I did not translate the --data-binary option and the @d:\my first file.jpg from the example to node.js axios proper parameters ..
curl -X PUT --data-binary @D:\My First File.jpg

Comment: The error `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) { errno: -4078, code: 'ECONNREFUSED'` is common when uploading large file using single upload link. By default, [GET buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectKey/signeds3upload](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signeds3upload-GET/) gives one upload URL only, please try to specify an extra query string called `parts` to get more URLs and to do file chunk upload.

Comment: See https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectKey-signeds3upload-GET/#example-1 and https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/direct-s3-nodejs-samples